# Why does my java code have an error?

Tags: java

This program is/was meant to be a Survey tool. Please help I have error:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:      Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to boolean    at
>   Conversation.main(Conversation.java:8)"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Conversation {
public static void main(String[] args) {
     String Ok;
     int yes;
     String age;
     boolean okay = age;

     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


     System.out.println("Please enter your name");
     Ok = in.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Hello, "+Ok);

     System.out.println("Please enter your age, ");
     yes = in.nextInt();

     System.out.println("(Yes or No)Are you sure you are "+yes);
     age = in.nextLine();

     if (okay = "No"){
         System.out.println("You are not allowed to lie \n in this program, please restart.");
     }



}
```

}

It is not finished yet.
Please help it is my first self made program.
I am aware that people could easily lie its just the principle.

Comment: `boolean okay = age;` can't assign string to a boolean. Please have a look at basics of JAVA.

Comment: You should take advantage of your debugging window.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, you can't assign a String to a boolean variable:

```
 String age;
 boolean okay = age;
```

Here's another problem:

```
 if (okay = "No"){
     System.out.println("You are not allowed to lie \n in this program, please restart.");
 }
```

Again you try to assign a String to a boolean variable, though it looks like you meant to compare a String to a boolean (which is also illegal).

Your variable names are confusing, but based on your outputs, I'd say you intended to compare the response to the `(Yes or No)Are you sure you are "+yes` question to "No" :

```
 System.out.println("(Yes or No)Are you sure you are "+yes);
 age = in.nextLine();

 if (age.equals("No")){
     System.out.println("You are not allowed to lie \n in this program, please restart.");
 }
```

Note that you should always compare Strings using `equals`, not `==`. Had that been the only problem in your code, I would have closed this question as duplicate.

Comment: what should i do to replac it?

Comment: @HyperTextMarkupLanguage Replace it with `boolean okay=false;` (or true).

Comment: (I don't understand the downvotes either.) As for OP: maybe you are confusing `Ok` and `okay` somewhere in there? `Ok = age;` would be legal (if not pretty - consider looking up code convetions for java).

Answer (score 1):

```
String age;
boolean okay = age;
```

You are assigning a `boolean` with a `String` object, that's the problem.

> cannot convert from String to boolean

**Another mistake is :**

`if (okay = "No"){`, you can not do this, `okay` is a `boolean` variable, and you are comparing it with a `String`, this is not allowed.

The correct code for it is `if (okay = false)`.

> PS: Anything enclosed in a pair for `"` is a `String` in java.

Example : "Jon" is a String.

Answer (score 0):

There are two compilation errors:

First Compilation error:

boolean okay = age;

You cannot assign string value to boolean variable, either you have to assign true or false.

Second Compilation error:

if (okay = "No")

Here you have to check with boolean value like:

```
if(okay == true)
```

or

```
if(okay == false)
```